# Why does my grid shows the entity fields - Vaadin 14

Tags: java, vaadin, crud, vaadin-grid

I have these entities.

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Language {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull
    private String language;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Sentence {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull
    private String wordInFrench;
    
    @NotNull
    private String wordInOtherLanguage;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @NotNull
    private Language language;
    
}
```

The pourpose is to create a drowndown combobox, which it does with this code:

```
@Route("addSentence")
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/vaadin-text-field-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-text-field")
public class AddSentenceView extends AppLayout {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    
    public AddSentenceView(SentenceService sentenceService, LanguageService languageService) {
        Top top = new Top();
        top.setTopAppLayout(this);
        
        // crud instance
        GridCrud<Sentence> crud = new GridCrud<>(Sentence.class);
                
        // grid configuration
        crud.getGrid().setColumns("wordInFrench", "wordInOtherLanguage", "language");
        crud.getGrid().setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
        
        // form configuration
        crud.getCrudFormFactory().setUseBeanValidation(true);
        crud.getCrudFormFactory().setVisibleProperties("wordInFrench", "wordInOtherLanguage", "language");
        crud.getCrudFormFactory().setFieldProvider("language",
                new ComboBoxProvider<>("Language", languageService.findAll(), new TextRenderer<>(Language::getLanguage), Language::getLanguage));
        
        // layout configuration
        setContent(crud);
        
        // logic configuration
        crud.setOperations(
                () -> sentenceService.findAll(),
                sentence -> sentenceService.save(sentence),
                sentence -> sentenceService.save(sentence),
                sentence -> sentenceService.delete(sentence)
        );
        
    }

}
```

But the results looks like this. I just want to see the attribute `language`. Not `Language(id = 5, language = fikus")`. What should I do for make that happen?

[image]

I'm using Vaadin 14 with CRUD-add on.
https://vaadin.com/directory/component/crud-ui-add-on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Language` field is an object, and as you haven't defined how to display it, it defaults to the `toString` method.

What you see in the grid is the output of the `Language#toString` method as generated by Lombok.

You could try changing `"language"` to `"language.language"` to get the actual String field. Another option is to manually add the column as `addColumn(sentence -> sentence.getLanguage().getLanguage())`.

P.S: You might not want to use `CascadeType.ALL` on your relation from `Sentence` to `Language`. This means that if you delete a sentence, it will also delete the language.

Comment: In what class are you talking about "language.language"?

Comment: For `getGrid().setColumns(...)`. The class `Sentence` has a field `language`, which refers to a `Language` object, which has a field `language`, which refers to a `String`. So the `String` value of the `Language` object would be `language.language`.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. Changing the toString method inside the `Language` class solves the problem.